# How to store/share from my app to skydrive?

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

I'm planning to use cloud storage in my WP7 app. Can I use Skydrive to store information or share information with other user's using my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh561314) to connect to SkyDrive. There's also an example tutorial [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SkyDrive-usage-through-Live-SDK-on-Windows-Phone.aspx).